# How do I write a negative trigonometric function as a positive number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I write csc(-1.2) as a positive number? I tried to figure it out and the only thing I can recognize is that cosecant is an odd function so we could take the negative outside the function and it'll become - csc(1.2).

Would this be the result? Is this how you write a negative trigonometric function as a positive number?

Comment: You mean "... as the function of a positive number", right ? In this case, you have found the correct solution.

Comment: $\csc(x+2\cdot \pi)=\csc(-x)\Rightarrow \csc(-1.2+2\cdot \pi)=\csc(-1.2)$ So the period is $2\pi$

Comment: @Peter yeah, that is what I meant "as a function of a positive number.". Thank you!

Comment: @callculus could you expand further on what this means? How does adding  "2⋅π" from cos(x) = csc (-x)? Is this an identity? -1.2 isn't a degree or radian, or is it? Does what you have commented have something to do with reference angles?

Comment: @IlIllIlllllllIllIlIllIIlIII It is a radian in my case. Otherwise the period is 360°. I don´t see that $\cos(x)=\csc(-x)$ is true in general.

Comment: @IlIllIlllllllIllIlIllIIlIII Any reply?